# Datatable datalist selected value

Tags: jquery, datatables, html-datalist, datalistitem

Please, what is wrong with this code. Adding the selected value from a datalist to datatables is not working. What am I doing wrong?
This is the HTML code:

```
<tr><td><label for = "user">User</label></td>
    <td><input id = "user" list = "user" ></input></td></tr>
    <datalist id = "user">
        <option value = "State">
    <option value = "Area">
    <option value = "Region">
    <option value = "Town">
    </datalist>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').dataTable();
    $('#addbtn').click(addrow);
    } );

        function addrow() {
    $('#table_id').dataTable().fnAddData
        ( [
            $('#age').val(),
                $('#user option:selected').val()
            );}
```

Comment: first thing that jumps out is that you're missing a closing square bracket

Comment: That corrected but still the same problem. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you get errors in Firebug? Have you checked that your 2 parameters are getting values?

Answer (score 0):

Both your `input` and your `datalist` have the ID `#user`. Only one element with the same ID is allowed on a page. Change the ID of one of the two to something else.